# Google API MapView OutOfMemory after setting the MapView to specific width and height

Tags: android, android-mapview, out-of-memory

i searched for this Problem, and i found some stackoverflow Questions about the same but without any idea how to resolve the problem.

I created an activity and i want to add a really small mapview (like 140w X 70h). It is only to show a small preview of where the place is. When you click this little mapview you get a new inflate to a new activity with the hole map.

MapView:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview" 
                android:layout_width="140dip"
                android:layout_height="80dip"
                android:layout_below="@id/attributes"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:apiKey="****"
                android:paddingBottom="60dp"/>
```

LogCat:

```
05-30 14:34:53.758: ERROR/dalvikvm(1608): Out of memory: Heap Size=4039KB,   Allocated=2768KB, Bitmap Size=625KB
05-30 14:34:53.758: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(1608): Shutting down VM
05-30 14:34:53.758: WARN/dalvikvm(1608): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x400259f8)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.resize(Unknown Source)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onMeasure(MapView.java:554)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:578)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:362)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:989)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:286)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:578)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:362)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3140)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:245)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8172)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:805)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1744)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-30 14:34:53.768: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1608):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

this is the error. When i use fill_parent it works, but i dont want a mapview with fill_parent.

Maybe you guys know another way to get a preview small image of the current (or given) position on the map as image.
Isn't it possible to show a small mapview ?

thanks

Comment: Hi Micro, I have tried your code and it works for me.

Comment: Can you post your entire layout file ? Seems like you have a lot of layout controls in there.....

Comment: hm.. okay, yes it is a really big activity with imageView, TextViews (8), TableLayout and RelativeLayout. But it is about some informations and i cant leave any of it away. EDIT: But why is it working with fill_parent??

Comment: So: The problem is the width of the mapView. When i put the width to fill_parent and a height to 80dip it works. It isn't what i want to have but it is fine as well. What could i do is, to set the marginLeft but it isn't really nice. So i cant resolve the problem but i have a nice looking workarround. If you can resolve the problem without Workarround, please tell me. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to show a static map without interaction I recommend the [static map api](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) from google. You can define markers, the center, the size and some labels and it returns a generated image that can be easily shown inside a ImageView. The benefit of this: You don't have to invoke a complete MapView for just a small map image. No overhead of memory or user interaction. Perfect for the scenario you have.